# OPTIONAL MATCH in Cypher not returning values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get nodes "A" so that it doesn't have a connection with any "B" OR that B doesn't has a connection with "C".

This is my query right now:

```
MATCH (a:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a) -- (b:B), (b) -- (c:C)
WITH *
WHERE (
    b IS NULL
    OR
    c IS NULL
)

RETURN *
```

The "a" results are correct. The problem is, that "b" is always null ("c" too, but that's expected).

I'm not using relationship predicates in the where because I need those nodes. This is a simple example, but I'm chaining more relationship levels and more filters (AND & OR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to split the `OPTIONAL MATCH` into two matches.

```
MATCH (a:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a) -- (b:B)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b) -- (c:C)
WITH *
WHERE (
    b IS NULL
    OR
    c IS NULL
)

RETURN *
```

When you are doing a single `OPTIONAL MATCH`, you are searching for a complete pattern and if it doesn't exist, then it won't be returned.